# matplotlib colormap choose colors

Tags: matplotlib, colormap, hsv

[image]

My current code looks like this: R is a 1D vector, Theta is a 1D vector, Phi is also a 1D vector, and E_d is also a 1D vector.

```
R=np.array(R)
Theta=np.array(Theta)
Phi=np.array(Phi)
E_d=np.array(E_d)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

#I have a 3D plot, with each axis representing a parameter, and the forth parameter is represented 
#via color
colors = cm.hsv(E_d/max(E_d))
colmap = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.hsv)
colmap.set_array(E_d)

yg = ax.scatter(Theta, Phi, R, c=colors, marker='o')
cb = fig.colorbar(colmap)][1]][1]
```

And the problem is as you can see, 1 and -7 (roughly) have the same red color. Is there anyway we can change the colors?

Comment: You are using the hsv colormap. This is explicitely a *cyclic* colormap. Maybe you want to use a different one, which does not have this problem? For available colormaps see [colormap_reference](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html). For how to create new colormaps see [colormap-manipulation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html)

Comment: In addition to the first comment: You probably want to use a sequential colormap with uniform lightness gradient such as `['viridis', 'plasma', 'inferno', 'magma']`. [this link](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) will also help